# Vue.js from Browserify to Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-4

Our current build process currently uses Grunt, vueify, and browserify to build our Single File Components and also pull Vue out of the SFC and into its own external file.

For various reasons (vueify no longer supported, async loading components, ...) we want to switch to Webpack.

However, I am failing at wrapping my head on how to make our current method work for Webpack. I've included our current build process below. I would love to figure out how make Webpack work for us. Any suggestions? I can't even seem to get started... How can I make Webpack compile our *.vue.js files into pre-rendered javascript files? At the bottom I've also included the contents of one of our SFC .vue.js files.

```
vueRuntime: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'node_modules/vue/dist/',
    src: 'vue.runtime.min.js',
    dest: 'js/rwd/libs',
    ext: '.js',
    extDot: 'first',
    options: {
        configure: b => b
            .require('vue')
            .transform(
                // Required in order to process node_modules files
                {global: true},
                envify({NODE_ENV: 'production'})
            )
            .bundle(),
        browserifyOptions: {
            debug: false
        }
    }
},
vue: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'js/rwd/',
    src: '**/*.vue.js',
    dest: 'js/rwd',
    ext: '.js',
    extDot: 'first',
    options: {
        configure: b => b
            .transform('vueify')
            .transform(
                // Required in order to process node_modules files
                {
                    global: true
                },
                envify({NODE_ENV: 'production'})
            )
            .external('vue')
            .bundle(),
        browserifyOptions: {
            debug: false
        }
    }
}
```

A sample *.vue.js file:

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const App = require('./something/components/Something.vue');

new Vue(App).$mount('#app-element-id');
```

Comment: For your issue, learning from boilerplate is a good start https://github.com/vuejs-templates. Although they are all in webpack 3, but necessary packages should be similar.

Comment: @blaz Yeah, I've been making good progress figuring it out. Seems writing out a question on SO is enough for me to start making headway.

Comment: I figured out a solution, when I have a moment I'll write up answer with links to sources.

Answer (score 0):

Having done a similar migration to Vue + Webpack recently, I found this blog post extremely helpful: https://itnext.io/vue-js-and-webpack-4-from-scratch-part-3-3f68d2a3c127

Another source of examples is the [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/). Unfortunately, the produced boilerplate is extremely hard to decipher because it requires a ton of node modules that all contribute minuscule amounts of config and also depend on other modules. So if you want to build something customized or actually learn how it all works together, it's more trouble than it's worth.